# abrupt browser close in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there a way to handle browser shut down or close in ASP.NET MVC? I know that  when we log out we can handle it using Application_End and Session_End in Global.asax,  when close or shut down happens abruptly is what I am looking for.

Comment: register a javascript method to call server using beforeunload event

Answer (score 0):

You can't *reliably* do this as your MVC code is running on the server and there are many paths to prevent solutions that you implement from working.  What problem are you actually trying to solve for?  There might be an alternative that doesn't require unreliable shutdown detection.

Comment: we have a requirement , where in the user can lock records in a screen , so when the user has locked the record and browser is shut down abruptly , its always locked in DB , alternative would be to write a job probably ... wanted to know if could do it in C#

Comment: You should consider putting an expiration on the lock and having the UI request renewal of the lock. If the browser closes, machine shuts down, network connection is lost, etc..., the renewal won’t be requested and the record can be made available